# Tabs like google play

Tags: android, android-tabs

I make my application that stores quotes, and I need to make it possible to sort quotes (by authors, by topic). And actually in tabs I want to show these ways.

But I really liked tabs like google play app

[image]

And I want to make the same in my application.

Tell me please, with the help of what I can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you searched so far?

Comment: @Bogdan: The widget you are looking at is not Tab, they are just view laid out using Horizontal Recycler View. TabLayout is above that, let me know what exactly you are looking for, I can explain more.

Comment: I looked in the documentation [link](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip), about PagerTitleStrip.

Comment: @Ishan Dhingra,So i need Horizontal Recycler View, please tell me more about this

Comment: Just search this on Google "Tags Android Github", you will get what you want.

Comment: take buttons in horizontal scroll view and set style (style to add curve)

Comment: @suraj shinde I think this will help me, thanks for explaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create xml in drawable folder and try this code to style buttons and use as a background of button like R.drawable.buttonStyle

```
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#1abc9c" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#1abc9c" android:endColor="#1abc9c" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Brilliantly, this is what I was looking for. Thanks.